# Angular TypeError: Cannot set property 'bindCallback' of undefined RJXS

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, rxjs

I have the problem that somehow I always get this error when I try to start my project (Ionic 3) with `ionic serve`

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'bindCallback' of undefined

I tried what mentioned [here on Github](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3060). But somehow it doesnt work.

This is my **package.json**:

```
    "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/admob-free": "^4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "~4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "~4.17.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
    "@ultimate/ngxerrors": "^1.4.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-admob-free": "0.23.0",
    "countup.js": "^1.9.3",
    "countup.js-angular2": "^6.0.2",
    "firebase": "^5.6.0",
    "install": "^0.12.2",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "npm": "^5.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.10",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.1",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  },
```

And this is how I import Observable in all of my files:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

And this is on example on how I use the Observable:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireFunctions } from 'angularfire2/functions';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class FirefunctionsProvider {

  constructor(private afFun: AngularFireFunctions) {}

  getShopItems() {
    return Observable.create((observer) => {
      this.afFun.httpsCallable('myfunction')({ text: 'Some Argument' })
      .toPromise()
      .then(resp => {
        console.log({ resp });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error({ err });
      });
    });
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Changing `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';` to `import { Observable } from 'rxjs';` worked but now I get a new error with my firebase function:

> ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

If you need more Information please ask Ill add it!

Comment: Hos do u import operators like `map` or `filter`

Comment: No. Do I need them? And how to import them?

Comment: post your code for that import

Comment: What RxJS version you have installed? `npm ls --depth=0`

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka added

Comment: This seems fine. But if you are using pipeable operators u need to import them as well like `import {map} from 'rxjs/operators'`

Comment: Someone answered my Question before and deleted his own answer: changing `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';` to  `import { Observable } from 'rxjs';` worked for me. Dont know why this person deleted his answer.

Comment: But now I get a new Error: `ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function` information added

Comment: @LukasReiner that is because it's for Rxjs 6 , but you are using 5x .

Comment: @LukasReiner can you post a stackbltiz demo ?

Comment: @Niladri updated rxjs and rxjs-combat to 6.3.3 still get this object error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I post the solution because the person who had the solution deleted his answer for unknown reasons:**

I had to change:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

to

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

with this dependencies:

```
"rxjs": "^6.3.3",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3"
```